# Standard charger for Macbook Pro insufficient

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I recently bought a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) and I am using the OOTB Power Adaptor (87W) and USB-C cable.

I am finding that when I run computationally expensive processes (e.g. I utilize multiple cores for data analysis), that the laptop will discharge (albeit at a slower pace) even when plugged in. This is obviously problematic if I have a continuous process, that is meant to last multiple hours.

This laptop is an upgrade from a 2015 MacBook Pro, with the Magsafe 2 Power Adaptor, on which I never experienced this problem.

Is there a solution to this? Perhaps an upgrade to the Power Adaptor (I think 87W is the max Apple provides) or the USB C Cable? Or is there something else?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  There's already several questions with provided answers surrounding this topic.  Although it might not be the exact same MBP, they're close enough.  Be sure to use the Search bar to find [these similar answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook+battery+charging+power).  They might help or at least give you options to try.

Comment: What gauge are the charging wires in your USB cord? 24 and up can kill charge rate. 22 is better. How long is the cable? For charging, 3 feet and under is best. In both cases, the resistance of the wires to current flow is too high.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Thanks, my cable looks about 6-feet, so I can try with a shorter one. What does the gauge refer to?

Comment: Gauge is a measure of wire diameter here. Smaller gauge is larger diameter, and less resistance per foot. Less resistance means faster charging: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_gauge